# How can i see the incremental updated value in sqoop job?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

Below is the sqoop job i have created

```
sqoop job --create sqoop_incremental_job -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db --username retail_dba --password cloudera --table categories --target-dir /user/cloudera/sqoop_incremental_job_categories --incremental append --check-column category_id --last-value 10 -m 1
```

For example: The last value was given as 10

Now i ran sqoop job for 2 times by adding the new records in mysql each time, So that the incremental would perform append to the existing data in HDFS.

The question is how the *last-value* is getting updated each time when i run job using `sqoop job --exec sqoop_incremental_job` and how can i see the updated value each time when i run the job???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively if the logs are missed. Use the below command

`sqoop job --show <jobname>` - It will list all the properties of the job

Refer to

> incremental.last.value - This will contain the latest value of incremental job performed.

It will be updated each time when we run the job via `sqoop job --exec <jobname>`

Answer (score 1):

As per sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_saved_jobs_and_incremental_imports):

> If an incremental import is run from a saved job, this value will be retained in the saved job. Subsequent runs of `sqoop job --exec someIncrementalJob` will continue to import only newer rows than those previously imported.

For seeing last -value,

> If an incremental import is run from the command line, the value which should be specified as `--last-value` in a subsequent incremental import will be printed to the screen for your reference.

Comment: It will be printed in the screen for the reference. Alternatively we can also view the value by using sqoop job --show <jobname>. It will list the properties of job incremental.last.value- it will be updated each time when we run incremental job.